# Template file is not overriding drupal 7 defaults

Tags: theming

Why node--type.tpl.php is not working? I've cleared drupal cache 100 times no results. Is there something else i must to do?

Answer (score 4):

Overriding node templates are done by placing node--'nodetype'.tpl.php templates inside your custom theme folder.
If the template isn't accepted after cache clear, check if the Machine name on admin/structure/types is the same as 'nodetype'.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you put node--underscores_between_words.tpl.php and saved it in your active theme directory.

Comment: in my case its news content type. i've used node--news.tpl.php and its not working

Comment: are you trying to style the page or the nodes?

Comment: im trying to style the node. page--front.tpl.php and so works as intended, but node--type.tpl.php not...

Comment: maybe try node--news--page.tpl.php or try node--idnumber.php

Comment: Is the Machine name corresponding to the type on the tpl.php file?

Comment: just noticed machine name was _news. Why drupal it adds by default?

Answer (score 0):

To override the node templates using node--type.tpl.php in your theme you need to also make sure that your theme overrides the system node.tpl.php template; this can just be a copy of the system node.tpl.php file in your theme if you don't wish to change it. Without it, any other node templates in your theme will be ignored.